From 52 cards, we draw N times with the return of 1 card each. Expected value of the number of different cards that were drawn. Solution verification
From a deck of 52 cards, we draw N times with the return of one card each. Calculate the expected value of the number of different cards that were drawn.
To calculate the expected value of the number of different cards drawn from a deck of $52$ cards in $N$ draws with replacement, we can use linearity of expectation and indicator random variables.
Let $X_i$​ be an indicator variable that is $1$ if the $i$-th card is drawn at least once in $N$ draws, and $0$ otherwise.
The total number of different cards drawn is: $X = X_1 + X_2 + \ ... \ + X_{52}$
The probability that a specific card (say card $i$) is not drawn in a single draw is $\frac{51}{52}$
The probability that this card is not drawn in $N$ draws is $\left( \frac{51}{52} \right)^N$.
Therefore, the probability that this card is drawn at least once in $N$ draws is:
$$\mathbb{P} (X_i ​= 1) = 1 − \left( \frac{51}{52} \right)^N$$
The expected value of $X_i$ is:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mathbb{P} (X_i ​= 1) = 1 − \left( \frac{51}{52} \right)^N$$
By the linearity of expectation, the expected value of the total number of different cards drawn is:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{52} ​X_i​ \right] = \sum_{i=1}^{52} \mathbb{E}[X_i​]= \sum_{i=1}^{52} \left(1 - \left( \frac{51}{52} \right)^N \right)= 52 \left(1 - \left( \frac{51}{52} \right)^N \right)$$
Is that correct?

Looks good to me!

Could not be done better (I think).
